# Android Multi-threading - How to notify main thread from Executor service

Tags: android, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to notify the main thread that all Callables executed by a Executor Service have completed.

At the moment I got a splash screen activity showing just an animated image. In the method OnCreate of this activity I load the application data in multithreading. Now I want to execute the goToMainMenu() method without locking the UI Thread.

With the following code as expected the method `task.get()` stop the UI Thread.

I could accomplish what I want with an Async Task by calling `((ApplicationClass) getApplication()).getApplicationData().LoadApplicationData();`
 on the `doInBackground()` method, however mixing up threads inside a Async thread doesn't sound the correct practice for this.

My Application Class:

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {

    private ApplicationData applicationData;

    public ApplicationData getApplicationData()
    {
        return applicationData;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationData = new ApplicationData(this);
    }
}
```

My Activity:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((ApplicationClass) getApplication()).getApplicationData().LoadApplicationData();
        goToMainMenu();
    }

    private void goToMainMenu() {
        Intent content = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, ContentActivity.class);
        content.putExtra("menu", getString(R.string.nav_title_news));
        startActivity(content);
        finish();
    }
}
```

My ApplicationData Class:

```
public final class ApplicationData {

Context c;
//There are more Variables to store work by Callables methods


public ApplicationData(Context context) {
    this.c = context;
}

public void LoadApplicationData() throws Exception {
        int PROCESSES = 6;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(PROCESSES);
        List<Callable<Void>> callables = Arrays.asList(
                new Callable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        LoadEventsLocations(c.getResources().getString(R.string.webserviceeventslocations));
                        return null;
                    }
                }, new Callable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        LoadTags(c.getResources().getString(R.string.webservicetags));
                        return null;
                    }
                }, new Callable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        homehtml = LoadHtml(c.getResources().getString(R.string.urlhome), c.getResources().getString(R.string.classarticletext), "home");
                        return null;
                    }
                }, new Callable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        objhtml = LoadHtml(c.getResources().getString(R.string.urlobjectives), c.getResources().getString(R.string.classarticletext), "obj");
                        return null;
                    }
                }, new Callable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        contactshtml = LoadHtml(c.getResources().getString(R.string.urlcontacts), c.getResources().getString(R.string.classcontacts), "contacts");
                        return null;
                    }
                }, new Callable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        commissionhtml = LoadHtml(c.getResources().getString(R.string.urlcommission), c.getResources().getString(R.string.classarticletext), "commission");
                        return null;
                    }
                });
        for (Future<Void> task : executor.invokeAll(callables))
            task.get();
        executor.shutdown();

    }

//There are more methods but keep it simple :)

}
```

**What you guys advise me to do?**

Comment: You can use handler that android provides: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: @HarshSoni I read that ExecutorService don't have a looper, isn't that going to be a problem?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now what you're doing is that calling get() on Future. It will block the thread until callable returns or completes it work. So I think as per your requirement you should call get() method in worker thread and after iterating through all the Future you can call your goToMainMenu().

Reference: http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/

Comment: Please let me know if answer helps?